# jpeg image data is shifted in ios UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, nsdata

I'm trying to send a jpeg image data from a tcp server to a tcp client and my client side device is an iphone mobile.

I compressed bitmap data to jpeg data in the server with opencv using cv::imencode.

If i send this image from server :
[image: simple rendered red triangle in opengl]

Then in the client side i have this image :
[image: iPhone 7 plus screenshot]

As see ,the image is shifted one pixel per row! Also in swift i used from NSData for showing the received bytes to UIImage :

```
let dataImage = NSData(bytes: encodedData, length: dlen)
let image = UIImage(data: dataImage as Data)
uiImageView.image = image
```

I see encodedData array in ios side and that was exactly same with the server sent data, And before of testing this in iphone i tested that in android and there , everything was right but now seems iphone doesn't decode the image rightly.

Does anyone know what is happening there?

Comment: If you print `dataImage`, is it the same as `encodedData` as it should be? Also, since you seems to use Swift3, why don't you use `Data.init(bytes: encodedData)` using `Data` instead of `NSData`?

Comment: @Larme Data result was same with NSData, but encodedData in unity and android is correct!

Comment: That was about opengl glReadPixels in the server side, in some specific width of framebuffers ,it could not read the buffer pixels correctly.